# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

Quick question as I can't seem to find a question regarding installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.

I've followed the instructions in the Ubuntu installation documentation as I'd like to install Ubtunu alongside windows 10, at least until I get the hang of Ubuntu. However, I can't find the UEFI editor in Windows 10 at all. (It isn't displayed where the tutorials say it is).

So, my question is, what is the best way for me to have both Ubuntu and windows 10?

Thanks in advance,

Nic

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is, what is the best way for me to have both Ubuntu and windows 10?

I suggest you to have windows installed and then use Live USB stick to install Ubuntu. After that, you are able to use **grub** to choose which operating system you want to use. I am not sure if it is the best way, but it is the easiest way, and it is what people usually do.

> However, I can't find the UEFI editor in Windows 10 at all.

In my opinion, it has to be somewhere it cannot just dissapear. But the question is - do you really need UEFI?